# Defined an Int but an array is expected?

Tags: java, variables, int

[Image of error;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dsoO.png)   In my program I am trying to use index to run through a set of data in order and I have declared it as an int but I keep getting the error, "array required, but int found".

```
public void calcHurricaneCategory() {
            for (index = 0; index < wind.length; index++) {
                windMPH[index] = wind[index] * mphInKnots;
                totalWind += windMPH[index];
                windAverage += windMPH[index];

                pressureAverage += pressure[index];

                if (windMPH[index] > 74 && windMPH[index] < 95) {
                    category[index] = 1;
                    categoryAverage += category[index];
                    category1++;
                }
                else if (windMPH[index] > 96 && windMPH[index] < 110) {
                    category[index] = 2;
                    categoryAverage += category[index];
                    category2++;
                }
                else if (windMPH[index] > 111 && windMPH[index] < 129) {
                    category[index] = 3;
                    categoryAverage += category[index];
                    category3++;
                }
                else if (windMPH[index] > 130 && windMPH[index] < 156) {
                    category[index] = 4;
                    categoryAverage += category[index];
                    category4++;
                }
                else if (windMPH[index] > 157) {
                    category[index] = 5;
                    categoryAverage += category[index];
                    category5++;
                }
        }   
    }
```

Here is how index is defined,

```
private int index;
```

I have seen questions like this before where the user actually defines index as an array but for now I am just completely confused.

Thank you any help is appreciated

Comment: Which line(s) is giving the error?

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: A side issue, but a windspeed of 95 or 96 mph (for one example) is unclassifiable by this code.

Comment: Post the error here directly as text, not as an image. And that errors cut off and doesn't appear to be what you posted in the question.

Comment: that is directly the text that BlueJ tells me, it only says "array required, but int found"

Comment: What is the definition of `wind`? Of `windMPH`? Of `category`?

Comment: private int wind;
private int windMPH;
private int category;

Comment: Note for the future: Providing a [mcve] demonstrating the problem makes it much easier to help you. Also see [ask].

Comment: @EnzoRomano Have it compile and get a full error. And again, the error in the image appears to be quite different than what you wrote here.

Comment: You can't access an `int` with an index - you would need to define `wind` and `windMPH` as `int[]`

Comment: Im sorry everyone im a new user to stack Overflow and a new programming student so I am just trying my best to figure everything out. The answer down below solved my issue and i am sorry I'm not good at asking the right questions yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the arrays as

```
private int[] wind; 
private int[] windMPH; 
private int[] category;
```

Answer (score -4):

Change this line

```
for (index = 0; index < wind.length; index++)
```

to

```
for (int index = 0; index < wind.length; index++)
```

or use

```
this.index
```

Comment: Neither of the suggestions worked... still same exact error

Comment: There's no way that a missing `int` would cause an "array required, but int found" error.